# How I do select from mysql latest value, if the value is not older than 3 months

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find clients, who have lot logged into my website in 3 months, to send a reminder.

My issue is if I do a interval query, there are always a result for a client, because the query select the date older than 3 months, even if the client has logged in at a later stage.

So I only want to see a result if a client logged in more than three moths ago. Currently I get results for three months a go, even if a client logged in more recent. If he logged in recently, the client should not show up in result

```
SELECT Client, IP, Date from iplog
WHERE  Date = (select max(Date)from iplog group by Client) AND Date < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this via an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT Client, IP, Date
FROM iplog ip1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM iplog ip2
                  WHERE ip1.Client = ip2.Client AND
                        ip2.Date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH));
```

The logic here is that we check, for each client record, that the client does not have any other record reflecting a recent login within the last 3 months.  If so, then all of that client's records would be returned.

Comment: I will. Waiting for the time lapse